# Are linker flags (linkopts) propagats in Bazel?

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

I'm building an Android library based on Tensorflow with Bazel.

Here the `BUILD` file

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libfoo.so",
    srcs = glob([
         "jni/**/*.cc",
         "jni/**/*.h",
    ]),
    copts = [ "-fexceptions", "-DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY",
              "-mfpu=neon", "-std=c++11",
              "-DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=0", "-DTF_LEAN_BINARY",
              "-O2", ],
    linkopts = [
        "-llog",
        "-lm",
    ],
    linkshared = 1,
    deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib",
        "@boringssl//:crypto",
    ],
)
```

The linker complains about not finding `-lpthread`, while I didn't add this flag to `linkopts`.

I've checked the executed command, and in fact there is extra flags on it: `-lz -lpthread ...`

Where did they came from ? Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: The C++ compiler configuration can also specify linker options, and that's likely what's happening here. Are you using the built-in NDK rules to compile this as Android? Can you show the Bazel command you're running?

Comment: @UlfAdams I already had an answer from your colleagues. See the answer bellow. You may find the command in the github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the tensorflow's issue tracker.

[@jart](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7288#issuecomment-277761166)

> Since copts and linkopts are viral and propagate to dependencies, -lpthread is most likely being inherited from @boringssl//:crypto

[@andrewharp](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7288#issuecomment-277801316)

> -lpthread is not necessary or possible on Android, so it sounds like the solution would be to add another condition for the select statement as in the linked commit [google/protobuf#1386:](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/1386)
>
> ...
>
> The only other workaround I know of that doesn't require editing the other repository is to create a dummy libpthread.so target, but that's pretty hacky.

Comment: The build encyclopedia says "The flags take effect only for compiling this target, not its dependencies", so I don't think the first statement is correct... or the docs are wrong: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.copts

Comment: `copts` do not propagate.  `linkopts`, however, do.  The docs are correct.